# Seeking ArcGIS Pro tool that calculates distance from different points to another feature class with multiple distance along road network

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, distance, network-analyst, road

Is there a specific tool that calculates the distance from points feature class to another points feature class?

I have a data set containing forest compartments (point), customer destination (point), and a road network.
I am after the distance in km’s from each compartment by forest, to all of the customer destinations.
With doing  simple explanation I have decided to draw my network in the simplest way.
Blue point are referred to as compartments, while red is customer destination, connected by road network. For example, I would want to calculate distance from compartment 1 to customer destination 7.

[image: example]

Comment: Yes there are tools in ArcPro that can help you answer this. It is the _network dataset_ and you need the extension installed and licensed to be able to use it. Recommend you open the help file and start reading about it.

Comment: yep, I've manage to create a network datatset,cheers. Was just wondering if you know of any of the specific tools would be useful for this? (location allocation, OD cost matrix etc...)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the [Closest Facility](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/networks/closest-facility-analysis-layer.htm) tool in the Network Analyst extension in ArcGIS Pro. Your forest points will be Incidents, and your customer points will be Facilities.